# Как реализовать дерево с чекбоксами

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как реализовать дерево с чекбоксами ? [рабочий пример](http://www.reestr-sro.ru/calc/sro-v-proektirovanii/)

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th class="left-th"><span class="arrow"></span><input class="groupswitchchb" type="checkbox"></th>
        <th class="right-th"><span class="dashed-span">1.Текст</span></th>
    </tr>

    <tr style="display: none;">
        <td class="check"><input name="chk[1][1][0]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>1.1. Подтекст</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="display: none;">
        <td class="check"><input name="chk[1][2][0]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>1.2.Подтекст</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="display: none;">
        <td class="check"><input name="chk[1][3][0]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>1.3.Подтекст</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="left-th"><span class="arrow"></span><input class="groupswitchchb" type="checkbox"></th>
            <th class="right-th"><span class="dashed-span">4. Текст</span></th>
        </tr>

        <tr style="display: none;">
            <td class="check"><input name="chk[4][1][0]" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>4.1. Подтекст</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="display: none;">
            <td class="check"><input name="chk[4][2][0]" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>4.2. Подтекст</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="display: none;">
            <td class="check"><input name="chk[4][3][0]" value="dng" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>4.3. Подтекст</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            .dashed-span{cursor:pointer}
            .left-th{width:90px;text-align:center}
            .right-th{text-align:left}
            .check{width:90px;text-align:right;padding-left:0}
            .arrow{display:inline-block;height:18px;width:18px;background:url(http://www.reestr-sro.ru/images/arrow_right_gray.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;cursor:pointer}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th class="left-th"><span class="arrow"></span><input class="groupswitchchb" type="checkbox"></th>
                    <th class="right-th"><span class="dashed-span">1.Текст</span></th>
                </tr>
                <tr style="display: none;">
                    <td class="check"><input name="chk[1][1][0]" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>1.1. Подтекст</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="display: none;">
                    <td class="check"><input name="chk[1][2][0]" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>1.2.Подтекст</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="display: none;">
                    <td class="check"><input name="chk[1][3][0]" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>1.3.Подтекст</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th class="left-th"><span class="arrow"></span><input class="groupswitchchb" type="checkbox"></th>
                    <th class="right-th"><span class="dashed-span">4. Текст</span></th>
                </tr>
                <tr style="display: none;">
                    <td class="check"><input name="chk[4][1][0]" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>4.1. Подтекст</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="display: none;">
                    <td class="check"><input name="chk[4][2][0]" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>4.2. Подтекст</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="display: none;">
                    <td class="check"><input name="chk[4][3][0]" value="dng" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>4.3. Подтекст</td>
                </tr>
             </tbody>
        </table>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('.dashed-span, .arrow').on('click', function() {
                    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('tr:not(:first)').toggle();
                });
                $('.groupswitchchb').on('click', function() {
                    $checkboxParent = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:first)');
                    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                        $checkboxParent.prop('checked', true);
                    else
                        $checkboxParent.prop('checked', false);

                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```